# SyntaxError: invalid character in identifier in line 2 just after import line

Tags: python, syntax-error

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('IQ_Size.csv')
features = df.iloc[:, 1:].values
labels = df.iloc[:, 0].values
```

​
Why do I get the following error: `SyntaxError: invalid character in identifier` in line 2?

Comment: Did you copy paste formatted text from somewhere in Line 2?
If yes, try deleting the line and typing it out again.

Comment: Please post the entire traceback, not just the final error message.

Comment: Yes I copied it from a text file, I'll write the code myself and check

Comment: File "C:\Users\sahus\Desktop\Forsk-Project\day34-35-challenge.py", line 3
    ​
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid character in identifier

Comment: You can (and should) [edit] your question to add this as ``code`` formatted text. Comments cannot properly represent tracebacks – that's especially the case for SyntaxError using a ``^`` pointing at the issue.